# In Chrome Dev Tools Timeline: what do the red marks mean?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, timeline

In Chrome 47 I see red marks (arrows) in the Timeline overview and detail view:

[image: Chrome 47 Development Tools -- red marks]

What do they mean? I suspect they indicate bad timings. Is this true? How can I get details?

I can't find detailed information [in the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering) (01-2016).

Older version did not show these marks.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.** The red marks indicate bad performance or warnings regarding the rendering. The bright red bar outlines a frame, the red bar is a marker to show the frame end.

This may include long running frames or rendering/layouting/painting issues that cause slower performance.

From the [Google Chrome Dev Tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool#overview_pane) (02-2017):

> 1. The red blocks above the FPS graph indicate long frames, which are likely candidates for [jank](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/).

When you zoom into the frames using the mousewheel you can examine each frame in detail. There is also a summary view at the very bottom (you may need to drag it up to open it), it may give you details to the issue.

In this case the frame took too long (was slower than ideal 16ms or 60 fps):

[image: Chrome 47 Development Tools: zoomed into one long-time frame (long running frame)]

---

In this case the code caused Chrome to recalculate the layout (which is cost intensive).

[image: Chrome 47 Development Tools: zoomed into one long-time frame (forced re-layout)]

You may open the item by clicking the gray array on the left hand side to navigate to the root cause. Note the Javscript file and line. Click on it to see the statement that caused the issue (in this case the **Layout**).

---